# Does anyone remember the 2 player stacking game with a deck of cards?

Tags: identify-this-game

Each player has a 4 pin stacking thing (like tower of Hanoi style) and then there were blocks numbered 1 to 3 in 3 colours (9 blocks total).
Deck of cards had all sorts of combos on, turned over a card and first player to get their stacks in that order won.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like *Number Rumba!*.

[image: Number rumba box shot]